# Securing a GWT app with a request param to be checked in a crosscontext attribute

Tags: gwt, spring-security, cross-context

My application is supposed to received a request parameter called *sessionId* which is supposed to be used to lookup for a crosscontext attribute.

I was looking at Spring Security to implement this and I think already have a good implementation of my AuthenticationProvider :

```
public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {
HttpServletRequest request = ((ServletRequestAttributes) RequestContextHolder.getRequestAttributes()).getRequest();
ServletContext servletContext = request.getSession().getServletContext();
String sessionId = request.getParameter("sessionId");
if (sessionId != null) {
    ServletContext sc = request.getSession().getServletContext();
    Object obj = sc.getContext("/crosscontext").getAttribute(sessionId);

    if (obj != null) {
        // return new Authentication
    }
} else {
    logger.error("No session id provided in the request");
    return null;
}
if (!GWT.isProdMode()) {
        // return new Authentication
} else {
    logger.error("No session id provided in the request");
    return null;
}
}
```

Now, what I would like to do is to configure Spring Security to not prompt for a user name and password, to let it reach this authentication provider call the authenticate method.

How can I achieve this ?

Comment: Can you show your security xml?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed my issue by reviewing the design of my security and going for something closer to the preauthenticated mechanisms that are already provided by Spring Security.

I extended 2 components of Spring Security.
First one is an AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter, usually his role is to provide the principal provided in the headers. In my case, I retrieve the header value and search in the context shared between 2 application for an attribute that corresponds to that header and returns it as principal :

```
public class MyApplicationPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter extends AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter {

private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(MyApplicationPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter.class);

@Override
protected Object getPreAuthenticatedPrincipal(HttpServletRequest request) {

    if (MyApplicationServerUtil.isProdMode()) {
        String principal = request.getHeader("MY_HEADER");
        String attribute = (String) request.getSession().getServletContext().getContext("/crosscontext").getAttribute(principal);
        logger.info("In PROD mode - Found value in crosscontext: " + attribute);
        return attribute;
    } else {
        logger.debug("In DEV mode - passing through ...");
        return "";
    }
}

@Override
protected Object getPreAuthenticatedCredentials(HttpServletRequest request) {
    return null;
}

}
```

The other component is the AuthenticationProvider which will just check if the authentication contains a principal when it runs in prod mode (GWT prod) :

```
public class MyApplicationAuthenticationProvider implements AuthenticationProvider {

private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(MyApplicationAuthenticationProvider.class);

public static final String SESSION_ID = "sessionId";

@Override
public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {

    if (MyApplicationServerUtil.isProdMode()) {
        if (StringUtils.isNotEmpty((String) authentication.getPrincipal())) {
            logger.warn("Found credentials: " + (String) authentication.getPrincipal());
            Authentication customAuth = new CustomAuthentication("ROLE_USER");
            customAuth.setAuthenticated(true);
            return customAuth;
        } else {
            throw new PreAuthenticatedCredentialsNotFoundException("Nothing returned from crosscontext for sessionId attribute ["
                    + (String) authentication.getPrincipal() + "]");
        }
    } else {
        Authentication customAuth = new CustomAuthentication("ROLE_USER");
        customAuth.setAuthenticated(true);
        return customAuth;
    }
}

@Override
public boolean supports(Class<?> authentication) {
    return PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationToken.class.isAssignableFrom(authentication);
}

}
```

I understand that it might not be the most secure application. However, it will already be running in a secure environment. But if you have suggestions for improvement, they're welcome !